# MS ACCESS - sum iif in a report

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple table that just has 5 columns (fields);
customers (text)
datemonth (text)
month (number)
year (number)
sales (number)

the sales field is the monthly sales for customer

i would like to have a report that will list each customer and their sales for each month; so there will be a box for jan2014, feb2014, mar2014, etc for each customer

Answer (score 0):

Create and save a query:

```
Select 
    Customers, 
    DateSerial([Year], [Month], 1) As MonthDate,
    Sales
```

Now run the crosstab query wizard using the query as source.